# Exclude a package from updating in composer

Tags: composer-php

Whenever I try to add a new package using composer like 
`"composer require packagename/package"` or use `"composer.phar update"`, I am getting all the installed packages updated. Is there any option in composer to exclude some package that I don't need to get updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you feel the need to exclude some of your packages from being updated, I'd consider this the beginning of getting into a dependency mess. You should clean up your dependencies now before it gets worse.

From my experience, the topmost reason not wanting to update a dependency is when you used a branch of a package instead of a released version. You should try to fix this as thoroughly as possible:

- If you are using your own packages, tag a release version for the commits you want to use. Then switch your software to either use that exact version, or use a wildcard version requirement like `1.0.*`, `~1.2` or `^1.3.4`.
- If you are using external code that you cannot influence directly, try to contact the developers of that code and ask them to tag a version. Tagging versions is important to maintain a sane dependency tree.
- If you cannot make the external developers tag a version, find a way to tag it yourself:
- - Clone their repository on Github, tag a version, and include your copy of the repository instead of going to packagist.org.
- - Create the necessary metadata in a "type=package" repository entry in your `composer.json` file.
- - Or at the very least, when depending on the branch, assign it a version alias to allow for a smoother transition later when the external project starts tagging their versions. Note that this will not fix your current problems at all, but it may make things better in the future.
- If all else fails, you might point to a certain commit id in your `composer.json`. This will

In general, you should always be able to run `composer update` unconditionally. If not, this is a warning sign for dependencies not properly declared in your own `composer.json` file.

The second reason for not wanting to update is incompatible changes in a package that were tagged as a bug fix instead of a major version increase. The solution for this would be simple:

- First you'd have to investigate the reason for such an error: Was it really an incompatible API change? If yes, raise an issue with the developers of that package. They should create a new bug fix version with that incompatible update rolled back or fixed, and if they want to keep their change, they should tag it with a minor or major version increment, depending on what they changed.
- If however you incorrectly used their code, somehow not using the public API, a bug fix is unlikely. You should try fixing your code by not using stuff that is not supposed to be the public API. For example, in recent versions of Symfony, the public API is explicitly tagged in the code and documentation - using something else will break at some point, even when doing "compatible" version updates like from 2.6.x to 2.7.x.
- Another way to fix it would be to exclude the newer version inside the `composer.json` file: Instead of `"external/package":"~1.2"` you'd put `"external/package":"~1.2,!1.2.5"` if you find that version 1.2.5 broke your software. Or maybe you are afraid of further updates also breaking your software, you'd put in `"external/package":"~1.2,!>=1.2.5"`.

One more thing to add: If you run `composer require`, you won't get updates for packages that are already installed. They are fixed. The required package will be selected based on all the installed versions, and it will only be installed if there is a version available that is compatible with all the versions already installed. Note that this will not work correctly if there are dependencies on branches of packages in both your own `composer.json` and the new package. The reason is that the branch name will be the same, but you'll never know which commit was being used. Maybe the new package uses a very recent commit of `dev-master` of a third package, and your own software a very old one, and there have been incompatible changes in between - this will break things without Composer being able to detect it.

Comment: Also what if the package version is "dev-master" ? will something like "external/package":"~dev-master,!>=1.2.5" work?

Comment: There are valid reasons for wanting to exclude a package! For example, I am developing a library, and I was to test my work in progress on a feature branch. So I need an app that's up to date with dependencies, but leaves my library alone.

Comment: If you need an environment (an app) to test your library, you are probably doing your testing wrong. A library should be able to be tested standalone, without being integrated inside other software. However, you should be able to require your lib's branch instead - and you are also able to directly include a local repository as the dependency source, so you can separate the library a bit, but still have it inside your app for testing.

Comment: For dev-master you can do something like: `composer show -i`then  `"nahid/linkify": "dev-master#0c4e58f"`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 25):

1. run this command and see what is your package version:

   ```
   composer show -i
   ```
2. go to `composer.json` and edit which package you want never change by `composer update` and write version correctly for that :

   ```
   "jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl": "1.3.*",
   ```

   change to :

   ```
   "jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl": "1.3.11",
   ```

Done! now if you run `composer update` this package not update.

Comment: what if the version is locked "dev-master" and you want to stay with your current installation?

Comment: For dev-master you can do something like: `composer show -i`then  `"nahid/linkify": "dev-master#0c4e58f"`

Answer (score 21):

From my experience, the best way to exclude 1 or some packages is to use --interactive in composer update.

```
$ composer update --interactive
```

When you do this you can select which package you want to update and skip the package that you don't want to update.

Answer (score 6):

You can supply the name(s) of a one or more packages to update:

```
composer update vendor1/package1 vendor1/package2 vendor2/*
```

and this will only update those packages.

This isn't specifically excluding, it's including, but it certainly makes updating specific packages much faster.

To avoid the update on using the `require` command, you'd could hand-craft the composer.json, (which isn't so hard) then run the above targetted update on the package you just added.

Also use --no-dev to exclude development packages (if you are not developing the packages you are depending on e.g. in production). This also speeds up the dependency analysis.

Comment: Most of the time I want to exclude one or two packages and update all others. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know of an exclude method, but you could pre-format a command line with all your wanted packages: `composer update vendor/package1 vendor/package2 vendor2/*` and just keep that command somewhere handy.

Comment: But I will have some 10 -  20 packages which will be increasing due course  while those which need to be excluded will be less. So it would be difficult to keep track of packages that need to be updated.

Comment: Well if you really don't want them updated, why not lock the required versions in the composer.json (i.e. don't use * wildcards or dev-master head-tracking).

Answer (score 2):

Using `composer require packagename/package`, you require a new package and you get a partial update for just `packagename/package` and its dependencies.

`composer update packagename/package` can be used to trigger the same partial update, but then in case you already have `packagename/package` in your `composer.json`.

Comment: What I need is exclude one or two packages and update all others

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use [`replace` property](http://www.darwinbiler.com/how-does-the-replace-property-work-in-composer/), however there isn't dedicated command for that, so you can run `composer require foo/bar` as usual (which will create `composer.json`), then add a new `replace` section for the package to ignore.

Or create `composer.json` file on your own. Here is the example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "radic/tmp-underscore-php": "1.2.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "patchwork/utf8": "*"
    }
}
```

Once you run `composer install`, the required package `patchwork/utf8` won't be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

@kenorb's solution seems to be the correct answer.

For e.g. to skip updating the package "radic/tmp-underscore-php", add it to the "replace" section of your composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "radic/tmp-underscore-php": "1.2.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "radic/tmp-underscore-php": "1.2.0"
    }
}
```

Now when you execute `composer update`, "radic/tmp-underscore-php" won't be updated.