# Is it possible to exclude a package from update while using composer update?

Tags: composer-php, neoscms

I am using Neos CMS for my website. Now I am trying to update the CMS via `composer update`. Inside my project I installed a package that is now abandoned. That resulted in a failed update because the `composer.json` inside the package does not require the newer version of the CMS. Basically I just need a way to completely ignore that package while composer is updating. `--no-dev` did not work. That resulted in: `Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.` Would be great if someone has an idea.

Comment: Please share more details. If any package you require is not compatible with any other package, it's obvious that updating that other package is not possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a package from updating in composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235449/exclude-a-package-from-updating-in-composer)

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the abandoned package is still available, you may create a fork of it, change the requirement settings and then include your fork like described in [How to require a fork with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer)

A much better way would be to exchange the package with something else which is still maintained. If you rely on the functionality of this package in your project(s), it may be worth to maintain an updated fork of it on your own.